# What would be the Maximum ERIP of cellphone in absence of 23dBm 3gpp restrictions?

Tags: cellphone, 5g, mimo

Consider a 5g cellphone with 4×4 MIMO antaenna (4 transmitters),wifi antaenna,& Bluetooth antaenna. Considering the 3gpp guidelines, current EIRP is set to maximum of 23dBm, which is maintained by the baseband firmware.

However in absence of 3gpp guidelines and no cap setup by baseband firmware, What would be the maximum EIRP if all the antennas were to transmit simultaneously? I have tried to look in PA circuit architecture, but no success.

Answer (score 2):

THere's no answer to this question. this is a question about the specific hardware, and no general answer is possible. Note that adding headroom for powers that you would never emit is costly, so don't expect huge differences between theoretical and standard-limited output powers!

Also, note that for multicarrier systems like you use in 4G/5G and especially MIMO, linearity is a big deal, so going closer to saturation in these amplifiers can have the opposite effect of what you wanted: instead of reaching more UEs in a farther distance, you might be reducing your combined data rate over all UEs and don't reach any further.

So, if you want a guess what the "maximum good output power ignoring restrictions" is, it's the "maximum output power adhering to restrictions", for most commercially used radio units.

Comment: Consider Samsung galaxy S20 ultra. The hardware specifications can be found on https://omdia.tech.informa.com/-/media/tech/omdia/assetfamily/2020/04/28/criticality-of-5g-modem-to-rf-integration-a-look-inside-samsung-galaxy-s20-ultra/exported/criticality-of-5g-modem-to-rf-integration-a-look-inside-samsung-galaxy-s20-ultra-pdf.pdf?sc_lang=en.     I am referring to peak power that can be emitted by the antenna

Comment: the antenna can probably stand several watts (for short durations). Nothing in the phone however could emit that amount of power, and as I explained, it's also not *desirable* to build a phone that can emit more power than specified by standards and laws. So, as I said in my last paragraph: $$\,$$ *the "maximum good output power ignoring restrictions" is, it's the "maximum output power adhering to restrictions", for most commercially used radio units.*